# How to use same menu Itemid for different views with breadcrumbs

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, breadcumb

I have 3 different views where the user will navigate from one view to another in a sequence way.  Assume the v1 list all student classes and v2 list the details of a single class and v3 list the details of a single subject.

[image]

V1 is the only view linked to the menu item 'Classes' and the item id is 107.  I am trying to manually add the breadcrumbs when the user navigate to other views with the same item id.

**v2 -> view.html.php**

```
$pathway = $this->_app->getPathway();
$pathway->addItem("Single Class", "index.php?option=com_example&view=v2&classid=1&Itemid=107");
```

**v3 -> view.html.php**

```
$pathway = $this->_app->getPathway();
$pathway->addItem("Single Subject", "index.php?option=com_example&view=v3&subid=1&Itemid=107");
```

When the user is in v2 the breadcrumbs is as 'Home->Classes->Single Class' which is correct.  When the user naviage to v3 then the breadcrumbs becomes as 'Home->Classes->Single Subject' which is wrong.  What I need as 'Home->classes->Single Class->Single Subject'.

Can someone advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

The Basic-Question is: How did you construct your component?

While displaying the v3, joomla/pathway must know the chain from v1 to v2 to v3

The v3 example does not populate the v2 item.

So you have extract from v3-Item the parent such as

```
$v3Item->classid

$pathway = $this->_app->getPathway();

$pathway->addItem("Classes", "index.php?option=com_example&view=v2&classid={$v3Item->classid}&Itemid=107")

$pathway->addItem("Single Subject", "index.php?option=com_example&view=v3&subid=1&Itemid=107")
```